# How can I make a service call in background while app is running ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

Anyone know. how can make service call during user interacts with particular screen. I mean I need to call additional data while user interact with app. but it still look like device is hang. help me please.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: "but it still look like device is hang" - from this, I assumed that OP tried to do it.

Answer (score -1):

For Get request use this code

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

or

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have not mentioned any code snippet, I **assume** that you are performing all your operations on `main` thread and that is the reason why your app is hanging. To be specific about `main` thread and `background` thread, we perform all the `UI` related tasks on `main` thread and `background` tasks on some other thread.So you can create another thread for your `background` task like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Perform your background task here
});
```

Comment: @Cristik As I have already mentioned that the asker has not posted any code snippet, so I can't tell exactly where to put this code. But my answer includes the reason behind the problem and its solution which the asker can put at appropriate place.